# Can you explain how OLS for non-linear data is working in statsmodels OLS implementation?

Tags: time-series, least-squares, statsmodels

reference: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html#OLS-non-linear-curve-but-linear-in-parameters

How is OLS in this implementation working? Is it finding the best line for each point along the way and recursively building the entire line?  There is not much online about OLS for non-linear data.

I'm questioning my results and hoping to find someway of explaining how OLS in stats models can produce a model like this.  Any explanation or references is appreciated. Thanks.

I'm doing a time series model trying to predict one parameter called "activity".  Following along the documentation for stats models (link) they show modeling non-linear data using OLS.

I used the OLS with my dependent variable being the activity for that day and the independent variables as lagged days of 1,6,7,8 and 10 days behind my predicted date.  I used about 80% of the days before as the training set and the remainder as a test.

[image: plot of actual vs predicted]

Comment: The data were generated by: $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2\sin(x)+\beta_3(x-5)^2+\varepsilon$. This is the model, too, and it is a *linear* model, because it is linear *in parameters*. Real non linear models are e.g. $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x^{\beta_2}+\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is such a neat question.  I'm going to describe a similar scenario where we use a single lagged feature because it is easier to visualize.

Let's say I have a time series that looks like this:
[image]

Not only do I plan to use `x` to predict `y`, I will also use a single lagged observation of `y`.  So to predict `y_i` I will use `x_i` and `y_{i-1}`.

The use of the single lagged feature puts my total feature space in two dimensions.  If I were to plot my two features against my outcome, I would get a 3d scatter plot, shown below

[image]

When you use OLS, you essentially fit a plane to this data. Here is that plane

[image]

the predictions from your model come from the plane that is learned. You are using more lags, so your plane lives in a higher dimensional space (which we have a tough time visualizing).

Comment: Great. Thank you so much for the detailed answer!